# Influential kings/emperors at the time of Maria Theresa

Tags: kingdom, habsburg

By reading the book by Basset [*For God and Kaiser*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300219679), the author seems to be pretty fond of the ruling of Maria Theresa. It is pointed out that Maria Theresa an influential Empress of the XVIII century. I was wondering two things: 1) whether if this is considered true in the western countries and 2) if there are  Kings or Emperors of the same period, in the East, whose influence could be considered to be the same order of magnitude as Maria Theresa was to her Empire.

Comment: I find it hard to accept that she was more influential than Catherine the Great or Frederick the Great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. I'm not sure how to measure "influential", and I'm not sure which countries are part of the west and the east.

Comment: Well, in the book it says that Frederick set the foundations for the decline of Prussian empire. And that this started in the incurse that he made to Silesia around the coronation of Maria Theresa.

Comment: Essentially he says that the influential part of Maria Theresa was to take a moribund kingodm and transform it in a "competitive" empire (unlike Frederick). Also that their reforms applied to the army produced one of the best cavalry units, at least in XVIII century.

Comment: I made the question less subjective by removing the superlatives and nominate it for reopening in its current form.

Comment: Thing is, most of what you can say about Maria Theresa goes double or triple for Catherine the Great.

Comment: This is precisely what I thought, and it appeared to me that the author was very biased towards the Habsburgs. Could you give an answer why Catherine superseded Maria Theresa?

Comment: If it's reopened.  At a start, she added massive territorial gains, including Black Sea ports,

Answer (score 2):

Reign of Maria Theresa as Archduchess of Austria, Queen of Hungary and Croatia, etc., Queen of Bohemia, Duchess of Styria, Carinthia and Carnioila, etc. 1740 to 1780.

Reign of Maria Theresa as Empress consort of Holy Roman Empire 1745-1765.

Reign of Joseph II as sole Archduke of Austria, King of Hungary and Croatia, etc., King of Bohemia, Duke of Styria, Carinthia and Carnioila, etc. 1780-1790.

Reign of Joseph II as Elected Emperor of the Romans 1765-1790.

Reign of Peter the Great of Russia 1673-1725.

Reign of Empress regent Elizabeth of Russia 1741-1762.

Reign of Empress regent Catherine II of Russia 1762-1796.

Reign of King Charles III of Spain & the Indias 1759-1788.

Reign of George III 1760-1820.

Reign of King Frederick II the Great of Prussia 1740-1786.

Reign of the Kangxi Emperor of Qing Dynasty Empire 1661-1722.

Reign of the Qianlong Emperor of Qing Dynasty Empire 1735-1796/99.

Reign of Nader Shah King of Kings of Iran 1736-1747.

Since none of the Mughal Padishahs after Auragenzeb (died 1707) can be considered a really great Mughal I think that is pretty much the entire list of contemporary or near contemporary monarchs who might be compared to Maria Theresa, though specialists might possibly think of a few others.

Thus if you want to do a comparative ranking of Maria Theresa with contemporary monarchs these are her main competition.

Comment: You don't list any of the [Ottoman sultans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:18th-century_Ottoman_sultans)?